# Mock Objects for Unit Testing in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, object, mocking

I just downloaded **OCMock** lib to use Mock Objects for unit testing in one of my apps. But before all, I wanted know to how to use them and what are the benefits of using mock objects?

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of Mock Objects, I think [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) has a fantastic explanation (not only limited to Objective-C or OCMock):

> In object-oriented programming, mock objects are simulated objects that mimic the behavior of real objects in controlled ways. A computer programmer typically creates a mock object to test the behavior of some other object, in much the same way that a car designer uses a crash test dummy to simulate the dynamic behavior of a human in vehicle impacts.
>
> In a unit test, mock objects can simulate the behavior of complex, real (non-mock) objects and are therefore useful when a real object is impractical or impossible to incorporate into a unit test.

For usage examples, the [OCMock website](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/software/OCMock/) has some good tutorials listed under the [Tutorial Tab](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/software/OCMock/#tutorials) on setting up Mock Objects for different uses and interacting with them. I really liked this tutorial titled [Poking Objective-C with a Test Stick](http://everburning.com/news/poking-objective-c-with-a-testing-stick/) which explains how to get OCMock imported into your project and getting started. It was written for Xcode 3 but shouldn't be difficult to interpret for Xcode 4.